# Regular expression formation

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to form a regular expression for below:

```
while(rste1.next())
{
e1 = rste1.getInt(1);
e1t[i] = e1t[i]++e1;
enp1 = rste1.getInt(2);
enpt1 = enpt1+enp1;
enz1 = rste1.getInt(3);
enzt1 = enzt1+enz1;
}
while(rste2.next())
{
e2 = rste2.getInt(1);
e2t[i] = e2t[i]+e2;
enp2 = rste2.getInt(2);
enpt2 = enpt2+enp2;
enz2 = rste2.getInt(3);
enzt2 = enzt2+enz2;
}
while(rste3.next())
{
e3 = rste3.getInt(1);
e3t[i] = e3t[i]+e3;
enp3 = rste3.getInt(2);
enpt3 = enpt3+enp3;
enz3 = rste3.getInt(3);
enzt3 = enzt3+enz3;
}
```

I need to replace enpt1,enpt2,enpt3...so on with enpt1[i],enpt2[i],enpt3[i]...so on.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regex:**

```
enpt\d+
```

The above regex would match all the `enpt` along with the following one or more digits. `$0` in the replacement part means, replace the matched characters with the matched characters. So it will be printed as it is. But we added  `[i]` along with `$0` , so the matched `enpt1,2,3` would be replaced by `enpt1[i],2[i],...`

**Replacement string:**

```
$0[i]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wE4fI1/9)

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression you are looking for is:

```
/enpt[1-3]/
```

of course `[1-3]` can be extended to  `[0-9]` to include more numbers and with a `+` will include 1 or more characters like `[0-9]+`